# Is there a way to make $this->dbAdapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE work?

Tags: php, syntax

`$this->dbAdapter` is an instance of `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`

I've tried:

```
$this->dbAdapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE // unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

${this->dbAdapter}::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE // unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

${$this->dbAdapter}::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE // Object of class Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter could not be converted to string

$this->{dbAdapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE} // Class "Local\Namespace\dbAdapter" not found
```

It seems all I can do is:

```
$dbAdapter = $this->dbAdapter;
...
$dbAdapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct way to reference this is:

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
```

or

```
\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
```

Its a constant, so it doesn't necessarily need to come from the instance itself. The reason you get the T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM error is because :: is a static scope reference that you can't use in conjunction with $this.